# Git ignores file and directory with same name

Tags: linux, git

So, I have a problem with Git, it ignores files and directories with the same name...

How to reproduce:

```sh
touch test.txt
```

```sh
mkdir test
```

```sh
git add .
```

```sh
git status
```

It will be show something like this:

```sh
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   test.txt
```

And the question is, where is my directory named `test`?

Comment: Empty directories are ignored by git tracking by default.

Comment: Git ignores my directory, even if it is not empty. Real project has a following structure:
```fish/
  index.js
fish.js```

Comment: do you have .gitignore file?

Comment: @crack_iT, yes, but it only has `node_modules` to ignore.

Comment: use `git add --all` because `git add .` only add files from current directory

Comment: I'm on macOS, if that is so important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `git add --all` because `git add .` only add files from current directory